# make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. in Linux

Tags: linux, makefile, configure, php-extension

I am trying to install memcached extension on linux.

Here is my current status:

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.5.tgz
tar zxvf memcache-2.2.5.tgz
cd memcache-2.2.5
phpize
./configure
make
```

And I got error like this.

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I am using AWS EC2 Linux AMI.
Please help me.
Thanks.